# Verificación de email en Laravel 8 + JetStream

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

Acabo de crear un nuevo proyecto Laravel de su versión 8, luego instalé `Jetstream` con `livewire` y luego ejecuté `npm install`, `npm run dev` y también lo publiqué `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views` ahora necesito validar el correo del usuario cuando se registra, y para ello implementé el `MustVerifyEmail` en el modelo `User` -> `class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail`.

El problema se presenta cuando agrego a las rutas `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` y ejecuto el comando `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`, me pide installar el paquete `Laravel/UI` -> `In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package` eso está bien? será que no es la manera correcta de verificar el correo electrónico? porque ya tengo el sistema de registro, login, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se debe aclarar que **Jetstream** es un *starter kit* y **Laravel ui** otro, entonces es conveniente mencionar lo siguiente:

- **Jetstream** usa internamente *laravel fortify* para las acciones relacionadas a las autenticación
- La habilitación o inhabilitación de características en foritfy se hace a través del archivo ubicado en: [**config/fortify.php**](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/registration.html#email-verification)

  ```
  .......
  Features::emailVerification(),  //debes descomentar esta parte
  .......
  ```
- El resto ya lo tienes hecho que es la implementación de la interface `MustVerifyEmail`

Comment: Gracias, lo ví en la documentación hace rato (Lo de fortify y descomentar esa línea)... Pero ahora lo entiendo mejor con tu explicación. Muchas gracias!